# Legacy application to communicate with cloud foundry using RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, microservices

I am new to cloud foundry and investigating possible ways for our legacy Java EE application to communicate asynchronously with an application running on cloud foundry.

We are doing a lot of asynchronous work already and are publishing events to Active MQ.

I know that cloud foundry has a possibility to bind with Rabbit MQ and my question is with the possibility for a cloud foundry running application to connect (listen) to an existing out of CF platform Rabbit MQ?

Any idea on other alternatives to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible. You can use a [user provided service](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html).

That allows you to inject the environment variables into your app, that are needed to connect to RabbitMQ (like host, port, vhost, username, password).

Once you create that service, you can bind it to your app. Inside your app code, you then can read the environment variables exactly the same way as you would do it, if you had used a RabbitMQ service provided by CloudFoundry.